# How does one prevent the submission of a webform if none of its radio buttons are checked?

Tags: forms, webforms, radio-button

I have a form with three radio button options, and a "submit" button (no checkboxes, no text fields). Yet if a user clicks the submit button, without choosing an option, the form still submits it, picking the first option anyway. What's the best method to prevent a form from being submitted if the user DOES NOT check any of the radio buttons? (My CMS is ExpressionEngine, and this form is generated using the CartThrob extension, just FYI. But it's not a CT issue as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can return false if there is no value for that input.

```
$('form').submit( function() {
  if ( !$('input:radio[name="myRadio"]').val() ) {
    alert('Fix this!');
    return false;
  }
});
```

You may need to change ! to =='', but that's the idea.